# KeyListener Not Working - how to fix?

Tags: android

I hope to build a page and includes a textbox. Once they user uses keyboard and add some characters and press the enter button on Android keyboard, it will return a toast. I learn tutorial and I know I should use the keyevent, I found the problems: １）　Cannot resolve symbol "OnKeyListener" and " text.setOnKeyListener(this);" indicates "in view cannot be applied to" It seems the keylistener is not correctly used and I cannot figure it out. THX

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ScrollView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity  extends Activity implements OnKeyListener {

    private ScrollView mScrollView;
    protected EditText text;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        text = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.text1);
        text.setOnKeyListener(this);


    }


    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {
            //mScrollView.smoothScrollBy(0, 500);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.d("msg","*****************%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%@@@@@@@@@");
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`View.OnKeyListener` is an inner `interface` of `View` class. Use it like below.

```
 public class MainActivity  extends Activity implements View.OnKeyListener {
    private ScrollView mScrollView;
    protected EditText text;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.text1);
        text.setOnKeyListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        return false;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Specify on which `View` you want `onKeyDown()` event.

```
text.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            switch(keyCode) {
                  case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER:
                  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.d("msg","*****************%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%@@@@@@@@@");
                 break;

                default:
                   return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Use `View.OnKeyListener()`